# WSO2 Identity server - how to update password history setting programatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 ISKM 5.10 . I have configuration item for password history setting under Resident Identity provider.

```
Password Policies > Password History setting .
```

I want to know is there any REST/SOAP API for setting the above value. I referred to the below document but could not find any details about how to set it programmatically.

```
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/validating-password-history/
```

Please help me to set this up programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATCH request to `https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/identity-governance/UGFzc3dvcmQgUG9saWNpZXM/connectors/cGFzc3dvcmRIaXN0b3J5` with the following payload can be used to update the `Password History setting` properties.

Payload:

```
{
    "operation": "UPDATE",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "passwordHistory.enable",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "passwordHistory.count",
            "value": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

`UGFzc3dvcmQgUG9saWNpZXM` - id of Governance connector category Password Policies.

`cGFzc3dvcmRIaXN0b3J5` - id of connector passwordHistory

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/identity-governance-rest-api/#/Management/patchConnector

Comment: How to find these Ids for governance connector and password history connector ?

Comment: You can use GET APIs in  https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/identity-governance-rest-api/ .Simply the id is the base64 encoded value of the connector name